# Weird spots in my mesh

Tags: mesh

In the mesh on the picture of a rear wheel I have weird spots and I don't tear them off.
It's not a light trap and when I add texture it gets worse.
Does anyone know what to do?

I work with Blender 2.83 [image]

Comment: Can you post the blend file?  There are several possibilities.  If you're using smooth shading you may want to set the object data properties -> Normals -> Auto Smooth on.  You might also try recalculating the normals. (In edit mode select all and then SHIFT-N). Or you could have some bad geometry.  There are several things you could do in that case.

Comment: Super!
The Shift-N and the Auto Smooth were the trick, Thanks !